# if i click the Checkbox the relvent result not displayed using jquery ajex

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am creating an e-commerce website. if i click a category on the checkbox relevant product should display.but result displayed undefined. what i tried so far i wrote it below.example if select the category as Tv on checkbox. tv product should display. i having a problem on jquery. can you check the jquery if i write correct or not **checkbox click part**.

Form Design

**Category**

```
  <div align="left" >
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" ><h4>Categories</h4></li>
            <li  id="displayResults" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            </li>
        </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 function getCategory(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get_category.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var catname = data[i].catname;
                    var catid = data[i].id;
                    var catstatus = data[i].status;
                    if(catstatus){
                        $('#displayResults').append('<li id='+catid+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><input id="cat_id'+ catid +'" type="checkbox" value="true" > '+ '  '   + ' <b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b></li>');
                    }else{
                        $('#displayResults').append('<li id='+catid+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b><input id="cat_'+ catid +'" type="checkbox" ></li>');
                    }

                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
                console.log(xhr.message)
            }
        });
    }
```

**Checkbox click**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#displayResults').click(function(){

        var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked');

        alert(cat);

        $.ajax({
                url: 'get_product.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {cat: cat},
            success: function(data){

                 var len = data.length;
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#Products").empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var price = data[i].price;
                        var image = data[i].image;
                        var description = data[i].description;
                        $("#Products").append("<div class='col-md-4'> " +
                        "<div class='panel panel-info' id='Products'>" +
                        "<div class='card-body'>" +
                        "<div class='panel-heading'>" + "<h4> " + description + "</h4> " +
                        "<p class='panel-body'>" + "<h3> " + price + "</h3>" +
                        "<p class='panel-body'> <img class='card-img-top' style='width:250px' height='250px' id='theImg' src='images/" + image + "' /> </p>" +
                        " <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>View More</a> </div> </div></div> </div>");
                    }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**get_product.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,cat_id,brand_id,price,description,image,keywords from products where cat_id = ? order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$cat_id,$brand_id,$price,$description,$image,$keywords);

 $cid = $_POST["cat"];
$stmt->bind_param("s", $cid);
$stmt->bind_result($id,$cat_id,$brand_id,$price,$description,$image,$keywords);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "cat_id"=>$cat_id,"brand_id"=>$brand_id,"price"=>$price,"description"=>$description,"image"=>$image,"keywords"=>$keywords);
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#cat_id") is wrongly used. There are many category your category id is defined as id="cat_id'+ catid +'".

I am assuming you need to check on single checkbox. if so then it will be better if you use input type radio.

But as you have use checkbox then you can do like this

```
 $(":checkbox").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                cat=$(this).val();
                alert(cat);
            }
        });
```

if you want to select multiple checkbox make cat as array and then pass it to data field.

Comment: how can write it sir.please write the code sir.  it is more helpful

Comment: $('#displayResults').append('<li id='+catid+' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><input id="cat_id'+ catid +'" type="checkbox" value="true" > '+ '  '   + ' <b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b></li>');        i am loading checkbox like this sir. it consist of many data. how can i select. i tried the code which you posted but it is not working

Comment: in which part you are getting an error, when you have write above did you get any alert or you are not getting cat id in get_product.php

Comment: alert msg i got undefined sir.yes i didn't get the cat_id to post to get_product.php page please please me to get the cat_id

Comment: I have checked same scenario and it's working . just inspect on your browser and check are you getting any console error and then check in network are you getting any 404 or any other error. and you need to replace this code var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked'); with my code.

Comment: i tried but still undefined. you can write the full code

Comment: are you able to create checkbox through ajax?

Comment: yes sir . getCategory() function i wrote above i created the check box using ajex

Comment: $('#displayResults').click(function(){

            var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked');

            alert(cat);   i wrote like this

Comment: any  upadateeeee

Comment: Change it   var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked'); alert( ) ...put the same that i have written...

Comment: i put like this var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked'); alert( cat ) result display  undefined

Comment: I know you have written the same just paste this..$(":checkbox").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                cat=$(this).val();
                alert(cat);
            }
        });     in place of this var cat = $('#cat_id').attr('checked'); alert( cat ) result